# iOS Raised Centre Tab Button

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have seen many examples of the raised center button on a `UITabBar`, most being just a `UIButton` placed over the top but all of these need coding on every view, Is there a way of creating this without having to program every view so it will appear on every screen, perhaps something in the app delegate?

I want to achieve a `UITabBar` with a raised circle in the center.

Comment: Please note that `IOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS) is not the same as `iOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS)

Comment: This is old, but as jeffery pointed out, if you ever ask yourself I don't want to do this in ever view, then you need to start thinking about subclassing. You should never have to nor is it good practice to repeat re-usable code.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UITabBarController`. I've found an example here: [Raised Center Tab Bar Button](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/).

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, and for your comments Michael, the problem I'm having is I just can't get this to work on my project as I'm using storyboards and I'm still quite new to all of this